# React Native Typescript Template doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have created a new project of React Native with a typescript template using the  official command `react-native init MyApp --template typescript` (a couple of times) and I can't see the changes I apply when I run the app.
Looks like the hot reload its working on terms of refresh the screen but doesn't apply the changes. In the case I create the app without typescript all its working properly.

I don't get any error so I have no idea what I can do. Below its the package.json in case this help but its basically the autogenerated file from `typescript template`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.34",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js"]
}
```

Any idea how I can get react-native working with typescript. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find the solution, and basically when you create the **react nativ**e app using the **typescript template** in the ./ of your project apperar 2 files named App (App.js and App.tsx) so basically the solution to get this working is go to the index.js and replace

> `import App from './App';` per import `App from './App.tsx';`

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App.tsx';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Also you can solve the problem removing the **.js** file so the index will point to the **.ts**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't execute the post installation setup script which takes care of removing the **App.js** file. Anyway, that's not necessary anymore as with the release of React Native 0.59 the post installation setup script is being executed automatically.

Comment: When I create native project with typescript template It still creates App.js and index.js, instead od .tsx