# React Native Typescript Template doesn't apply changes

Tags: typescript, react-native

The provided solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608520/735226) didn't work for me completely.

I am trying to use react-native with Typescript, so I set up a project with `react-native init MyApp --template typescript`. When I run `react-native run-android` I basically have a couple of saves to the App.tsx file and the changes do get applied fine. But after a while it doesn't apply the changes anymore and I have to restart the metro bundler.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Are you using hot reloading or live reloading? Hot reloading is known to be more buggy than the latter.

Comment: I tried both, neither did work correctly.

Comment: I just worked on a React Native project, and when the reload didn't trigger on save, I saved my file several times more in a row. Ugly hack, but that worked. Else, there are many bug reports on React Native's reload, including [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18899) where @cihadturhan proposed a websocket-level fix for an issue that really looks like yours

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, hope you have figured it out in the meantime.

In the old versions of the TypeScript template you had to run a post-installation script manually in order to complete the project setup.

This isn't necessary anymore as it is being done automatically in the latest React Native version.